# Unable to change flipview''s background in uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I found that flipview's background is unable to change...

```
<Page
    x:Class="CoreSocialistValues.Views.ImageGalleryCSV2DetailPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:models="using:CoreSocialistValues.Models"
    KeyDown="OnKeyDown"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="showFlipView" Completed="OnShowFlipViewCompleted">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="flipView" BeginTime="0:0:0.5">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="shapeGrid" BeginTime="0:0:0.5">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="previewImage" BeginTime="0:0:0.6">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <FlipView Background="SeaGreen"
            x:Name="flipView"
            Visibility="Visible"
            FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="1,1,1,1"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedImage, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:SampleImage">
                    <Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly">
                        <Image
                            x:Name="detailImage"
                            Stretch="None"
                            Source="{x:Bind Source, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>


        <Grid x:Name="shapeGrid"/>
        <Image
            x:Name="previewImage"
            Style="{StaticResource DetailImageStyle}"
            Source="{x:Bind SelectedImage.(models:SampleImage.Source), Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And I tried to modify the template of flipview, nothing happened.

I create a new project, flipview's background can be changed....

So is there any way to change it?

Comment: I just tried changing the color and couldn't reproduce your issue.. (https://imgur.com/a/IVWAtrd) .. can you post the whole XAML code ? maybe something's overlapping your flipview

Comment: From what I see from the xaml code, `previewImage` is above all the elements in your `Grid` and is filling the whole grid with its content. you might want to consider `Grid.RowDefinitions`

Comment: I set previewImage's visiability to collapse, still the same.

Comment: @Vincent Pratyay's suggestion was correct. The issue is your `previewImage` cover the FlipView control, if you set visibility to collapse, you should see it. See [ScreenShot and xaml code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq). If you still could not solve this issue, please upload a [mcve]. I could help diagnose this issue.

Comment: Hi, @XavierXie-MSFT. My full code is here https://github.com/hupo376787/CoreSocialistValues. Please see ImageGalleryCSV2DetailPage, I want to set the background to transparent, so that the whole window background seems blured.

Comment: @Vincent Friendly reminder: Please pay attention to protecting your own privacy. The code sample that you uploaded contains the store certificate etc.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have deleted my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please see ImageGalleryCSV2DetailPage, I want to set the background to transparent, so that the whole window background seems blured.

The issue of setting background for your `FlipView` unsuccessfully is because you have a custom style for your `FlipView` in `/Styles/FlipView.xaml`. In this style, you set the background to 'Transparent' for the `Grid` which is the root panel in your `FlipView`'s ControlTemplate. It will cover the background when you set background for `FlipView`. This is the reason why you always cannot see the backgrond when you set for `FlipView`.

You could using `{TemplateBinding Background}` like the following:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlipView">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
......
```

After that, if you set `Background="SeaGreen"` for `FlipView`, you will see it works well.

[image]

Then, you said `that the whole window background seems blured`.

To achieve this effect, you need to apply some [Acrylic brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) to the background.

For example,

```
<FlipView 
        x:Name="flipView" Background="{StaticResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowBrush}"
......
```

Comment: Hi, it works. At first, I thought if I set FlipView's background to transparent, it will show a blured windows, since my whole window's background is already blured. But now it seems not. I have to set separately for it.